# display a success message after form submission in smarty php template?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am trying to display a success message after form submission in smarty php template.

once a user registers on the site and their data has been entered into the mysql database, I need to display a success message on the same page.

I have the following in my php page:

```
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    $success = "";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
        $db_conx,
        "INSERT INTO (XXX, XXX, XXX) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    ;
    //after validation, of course
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $firstname, $lastname, $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);//<-- CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF!
        //update was successful
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
    }
    printf("<script>location.href='register.PHP'</script>");

    $success = "You have successfully registered your account.";
    exit();
        } 
      } 
    } 
$smarty->assign("success",$success);
```

And I have this in my template page right above the `<form>` tag:

```
{$success}
```

however, I get the data entered into mysql and I get redirected to the register.php page but I don't get the success message!

could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share more of your code...are you redirecting the user again on the same page after update successful or its the another page

Comment: I think this can help http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete

Comment: @SkyKumar, there are no more codes to share. that is exactly what I have! I am redirecting the users on the same page, yes.

Comment: @SkyKumar, No, I know how to display error message if a field is missing etc in a form in pure php. smarty is a bit different and also I am trying to display success message after form submission. please read the question again. :)

Comment: What's the need or redirecting user.. 
just echo out your success msg

Comment: @SkyKumar, because if I don't redirect the users, they will get pointed to a blank php page which is the register.php page. as I said working with smarty is a bit different than working with PHP on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you redirect script to register.php and then try to assign smarty variables. It won't work because earlier redirection will be done. Looking at your code it seems that you always redirect to register.php so you should move some code from this file to register.php

in register.php you could simple place:

```
$success = "You have successfully registered your account.";
$smarty->assign("success",$success);
$smarty->display('register.tpl");
```

And in register.tpl you can use

```
{$success}
```

However looking at your code it's not the best way it should be done. I don't see any point to redirect user to another page. In addition you make redirection always and set variable success information that everything was success even if it was failure - in code from anwer you should place success and redirection to register.php inside if so only when registering was successful.